# get wrong value,while adding two number

Tags: ios

I am new in IPhone Programming.

I want to add two number that come from Text Fields & will show result in another TextField.

But the result I get is wrong. like : 5 + 8 = 5 - I always get the first number.

Here is my button click event.

```
    - (IBAction)Add:(id)sender {

    int valueOne= [self.firstNum.text intValue];
    int valueTwo =[self.secondNum.text intValue];

    int result = valueOne + valueTwo;

    NSLog(@"The result is %d",result);

    [self.resultTxtField setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", result]];
}
```

Comment: log the values and see if there is an mistake there

Comment: @MerleaDan i logged. i got the first number also .:(

Comment: try with breakpoints..

Answer (score 0):

well , after getting Logged, i get zero (0) value from second TextField.So, can't the result value is always first number.

**Solution**: I again dragged the text field from story board to my viewcontroller.h file. then i get the correct result.